# Where is the UPN claim for a guested user?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have a secondary AAD with guested users from a primary AAD.  The token generated for the guest user appears to be missing the upn claim, but we are relying on the fact that the upn claim exists as that is what we are using to map users across systems.

I understand that the upn may be missing for guested Microsoft Live accounts, but these are full AAD accounts, just in another AAD. Microsoft’s documentation also suggests the unique_name  claim may not actually be unique!!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims

Could you tell me what determines the value of the unique_name claim?

Is this safe for us to use this claim to fallback to if the upn claim does not exist or is an externally guested user?

Guest user token content

```
{
    ..,...
    "tid": "xxxxxxxx-7ea7-413c-96bc-3f3aba133732",
    "unique_name": "testAdmin@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Regular user Token content:

```
{
    ......
    "tid": "xxxxxxxx-72d8-4715-b14f-990c93843416",
    "unique_name": "testAdmin@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "upn": "testAdmin@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ver": "1.0"
```

}

I know you would probably like us to use the “oid” but this would cause us issues between environments as the same user will be a different value in each AAD.

Comment: Just want to mention that you are right that unique_name is not "unique". Read the description on the [token claims page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims). `Provides a human readable value that identifies the subject of the token. This value is not guaranteed to be unique within a tenant and is designed to be used only for display purposes.`

Comment: So one of my questions is how is that value calculated or determined in a tenant? What can an AAD Admin do to a user record to change it? Also as an architect and someone who likes good clean naming, why is that claim called unique_name?

Comment: We're in the exact same situation. Until now, we've used `unique_name`, but as it turns out, this identifier does not match the value of UPN in all cases, e.g. for tenant guest users. I think our solution will be to use `upn` with fallback on `unique_name`, and for further Graph API user queries, query all users and check for both `userPrincipalName` and `mail` for a match.

About the naming of `unique_name`, I personally had a laugh reading Microsoft's documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Tokens (well, tokens where `ver==1.0`) representing guest users in Azure AD will indeed be missing the `upn` claim, but will contain the `unique_name` claim, as you've discovered.  This applies equivalently to guest users from other Azure AD tenants, as well as guest users from external identity providers.

The value of the `unique_name` claim for guest users from other Azure AD tenants will be the user's UPN, if available, or otherwise falls back to the user's email address.  For other types of guest users, the `unique_name` will take other formats & values.  The idea is that the `unique_name` is the best-effort human-readable identifier for the guest user.

In any case, the `unique_name` value can be changed, and in rare cases, collisions might occur.  That's why the documentation recommends against using it as a primary user identifier.  The recommended user identifier in the Azure AD system is the object ID, or `oid`.

Yes, the `oid` will be different for the same human across different tenants.  But that's sort of the point of the Azure AD tenanted model. A guest user in another tenant is meant to appear as a completely different user to the application than the user in its "home" tenant.  If you want to map these two users together, the best you can do is use heuristics, like the `unique_name`.

I'd recommend that you file requests on feedback.azure.com for a couple things:

1. A reliable user identifier that can identify users across tenants.
2. Better documentation on how to handle guest accounts in AAD.

Comment: Any MS Docs that can be linked to back up the details shared here? Such as `unique_name` using the UPN claim (that v1.0 used to have) if available but then using `Email` as fallback?